# Display Group does not rotate - Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to rotate a group around its centre point once. But it is not working. Please help me where am I wrong? Thank you

```
local colorPalette = display.newGroup()

colorPalette, greenColor, darkGreenColor, darkBrownColor, brownColor =  artassets.getColorPalette()    --- displaying objects


    paletteGroup:insert(colorPalette)  ---inserting them in group
    paletteGroup:insert(greenColor)
    paletteGroup:insert(darkGreenColor)
    paletteGroup:insert(darkBrownColor)
    paletteGroup:insert(brownColor)

    paletteGroup.anchorChildren = true
    paletteGroup.anchorX = 0.5
    paletteGroup.anchorY = 0.5
    paletteGroup:rotate( 90 )
```

Comment: where do you define paletteGroup?
I think your first line should contain paletteGroup instead of colorPalette if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score -1):

It should be something wrong with your objects definition. This is fairly straitforward example:

```
    jobText = display.newText( "test", 50, 50, systemFontBold, 50 )
    jobText:setFillColor( 1,1,0 )

local function object( event )

    if event.phase == "began" then
        print( a/0 )

    end
    return true
end
local image = display.newImageRect( "bg.jpg", 100, 100 )
image.x = display.contentCenterX
image.y = display.contentCenterY
image.alpha = 0.5

jobText:addEventListener( "touch", object )

local paletteGroup = display.newGroup()
jobText:rotate(45)

    paletteGroup:insert(image)
    paletteGroup:insert(jobText)


    paletteGroup.anchorChildren = true
    paletteGroup.anchorX = .1
    paletteGroup.anchorY = .1
    paletteGroup:rotate( 20 )
```